# A 'ThreadSafe' Observable Collection - C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Seeing as a concurrent collection does not exist in .net that allows specific items to be removed, I have put together the following class.

It's important to note that it is only threadsafe until the `LockTimeout` on a given operation expires.

The main goal was to to guard against cheeky 'InvalidOperationException: Collection Was Modified' exceptions, which occur if I'm enumerating in one thread, and adding / removing in another.

I've defaulted the `LockTimeout` to 10 seconds, but in reality, 1 second would still be plenty (in my user case at least).

Lastly, this specific implementation also incorporates `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class ThreadsafeObservableCollection<T> : IList<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<PropertyChangedEventArgs> _propertyChangedEvents = new ConcurrentQueue<PropertyChangedEventArgs>();

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> _collectionChangedEvents = new ConcurrentQueue<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>();

    private readonly ObservableCollection<T> _collection;

    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    private static TimeSpan LOCK_TIMEOUT = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    public ThreadsafeObservableCollection()
    {
        _collection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        _collection.CollectionChanged += _collection_CollectionChanged;
        (_collection as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += _collection_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Wait()
    {
        while (!_semaphore.Wait(LOCK_TIMEOUT))
            _semaphore.Release();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            _collection.Add(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            _collection.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        Wait();
        bool result;
        try
        {
            result = _collection.Contains(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
        return result;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            Wait();
            int count;
            try
            {
                count = _collection.Count;
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
            FireOutstandingEvents();
            return count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            Wait();
            T item;
            try
            {
                item = _collection[index];
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
            FireOutstandingEvents();
            return item;
        }
        set
        {
            Wait();
            try
            {
                _collection[index] = value;
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release();
            }
            FireOutstandingEvents();
        }
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            _collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        Wait();
        int index;
        try
        {
            index = _collection.IndexOf(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
        return index;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            _collection.Insert(index, item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        Wait();
        bool result;
        try
        {
            result = _collection.Remove(item);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
        return result;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            _collection.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
        FireOutstandingEvents();
    }

    private void FireOutstandingEvents()
    {
        while (_propertyChangedEvents.TryDequeue(out PropertyChangedEventArgs arg))
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, arg);
        while (_collectionChangedEvents.TryDequeue(out NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs arg))
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, arg);
    }

    private void _collection_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _propertyChangedEvents.Enqueue(e);
    }

    private void _collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _collectionChangedEvents.Enqueue(e);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<T>)_collection.ToArray()).GetEnumerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        Wait();
        try
        {
            return _collection.ToArray().GetEnumerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like [this](https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/10023516) one. The Thread-safety here achieved by pushing each modification call to UI Thread. The only restriction here: you must construct the instance in the UI Thread. It's easy as it could be. I checked, it's totally thread-safe. I'm using it in almost all of my WPF projects.

Comment: Also your implementation contains a problem. To interact with UI Controls properly you must fire the events in the UI Thread. Otherwise you may probably break the state of the Items Control by Race Condition at `CollectionChanged` calls e.g. new fire before previous was handled by UI.

Comment: Thus the solution in review is ok to eleminate `Collection was modified` but not ready to use with UI Data Bindings. The solution in the first comment doesn't fix this exception but fix another one `Operation not supported` when modification call performed from some pooled thread. One more question: why `SemaphoreSlim` instead of `lock`?

Answer (score 3):

The `Wait` method is not correct.
If the timeout expires the semaphore is released without being taken.
This may allow code to run immediately afterwards because there's a slot available (not really as it was already taken but erroneously released) but in the future when `Release` is called it will fail because the semaphore has already reached its maximum size.

```
private void Wait()
{
    while (!_semaphore.Wait(LOCK_TIMEOUT))
        _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Every *successful* call to `Wait` **must** be paired with a call to `Release`.
A `Wait` returning false is not successful.